# Bootstrap data error displaying breaks the layout

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Sorry if its a stupid question but I'm unable to figure this simple layout

This is my simply input field with a email field and if the users enters invalid email it shows error as seen below:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="txtEmail" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Email Address:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div class="input-group  col-md-12 form-group has-feedback">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
            </span>
            <input type="email" id="txtEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email Address" data-minlength="50" data-error="Please enter valid email address" required>
            <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the result is displayed as:

[image]

I need something as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Can you recreate issue here? https://jsfiddle.net/1jja9ozq/

Comment: `</div>` was missing in your code.